# Excel VBA: Flipping cells horizontally along with their formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic

I am trying to write a code which will flip my cells horizontally via Virtual Basic along with cells formatting (I need background colour to flip too).

What I mean by flip is this:

[image: graphic interpretation]

I came with the code which does the actual flip of cell values, but DOES NOT move all formatting. Is it possible to flip backgrounds too?

The code I have is:

```
Sub Fliphorizontally()
'updateby Extendoffice
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Arr = WorkRng.Formula
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    k = UBound(Arr, 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) / 2
        xTemp = Arr(i, j)
        Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, k)
        Arr(i, k) = xTemp
        k = k - 1
    Next
Next
WorkRng.Formula = Arr
End Sub
```

If that makes a difference - I use Mac, not PC

Comment: Can you update your question to provide some clarication. Does flip mean reverse the order of the characters in a string?  That seems to be your example. What does it mean to flip a background color?  i. e. If  the background is light yellow, what would the flipped color be?

Comment: @BlindSpots, I clarified in the description.

Comment: I understand. A way to express this is you would like to reverse the order of a range of cells in a row.  After the reversal the contents of the last cell in the range would replace the contents of 1st, the 2nd last would replace the 2nd, 3rd last the 3rd, and so on. Also formatting would move with the cell contents.

Comment: @BlindSpots, yes, exactly. It's like a mirror. The thing is - I have all of them in the wrong order. They are strings of text and backgrounds along them. I actually added a graphical interpretation of what I mean, so it's clear now. 
The code I already have moves values, but does not move colours

Comment: This will help: [Stack-Overflow Return background color of selected cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520570/return-background-color-of-selected-cell)

Comment: Thanks @BlindSpots, but it doesn't help much. I'm not very good in VBA. The topic you suggested returns values of background. I simply need to move the formatting. I'm not sure is there an easier way of doing this

Comment: I don't think that VBA will work well for you as that one looks like it is using arrays which would only move values. I suggest you just `record a macro` of you copying and pasting each cell into a new space then cut that new set back to the old space (if you want to do that).

Comment: You could use the formula `=SORTBY(C2:F2,SORT(COLUMN(C2:F2),,-1,TRUE))` and conditional formatting to colour the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:F2") 'Your original data.
    
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Sheet1.Range("C3") 'First cell of the reversed data.
    
    Target.Resize(, SourceRange.Columns.Count) = ReverseRange(SourceRange)
    
    Dim ColourRef As Variant
    ColourRef = ReverseRange(SourceRange, True)
    Dim Ref As Variant
    Dim Cntr As Long
    For Each Ref In ColourRef
        Target.Offset(, Cntr).Interior.Color = Ref
        Cntr = Cntr + 1
    Next Ref

End Sub

 
Public Function ReverseRange(Source As Range, Optional ReverseColour As Boolean = False) As Variant

    Dim Cell As Range
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each Cell In Source
            .Add IIf(ReverseColour, Cell.Interior.Color, Cell.Value2)
        Next Cell
        .Reverse
        ReverseRange = .ToArray
    End With

End Function
```